# json_encode a MySQL table and urldecode Each Row

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json

Here's what I got. I have a MySQL table, in this case 'businesses' which has a many rows of urlencode() data. I am trying to use a php script (getTable.php) to grab the table urldecode() each row and then use a json_encode to send the data as an array back to javascript. Here's what i have so far.

```
$table = $_GET['table'];    
$query = "SELECT * FROM $table";
$jsonOut = array();
while($result = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query))) 
{
    foreach($result as &$value) 
     {
      $value = urldecode($value);
     }
$jsonOut[] = $result;
}
echo (json_encode($jsonOut));
```

Obviously, I'm doing something wrong because I'm causing an infinite loop and nothing ends up working. Any help wold be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
$table = $_GET['table'];    
$query = "SELECT * FROM $table";
$jsonOut = array();
$result = mysql_query($query);
while($result = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{
    $jsonOut[] = $result;
}
echo (json_encode($jsonOut));
```

In fact the query has to be executed only once, not once for each iteration of the `while` loop, or else you'll end up with an infinite loop!

Also, as a side note, you should avoid using `mysql_*` functions as they're now deprecated, try to switch to `PDO` if you can.

EDIT:

If you need to `urldecode` each row, replace

```
$jsonOut[] = $result;
```

with

```
$jsonOut[] = array_map('urldecode', $result);
```

inside the `while` loop.

Comment: This works, but it still is not doing the URLDecode for every row. Any ideas to implement URLDecode?

Answer (score 1):

This is the infinite loop you're talking about

```
while($result = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query)))
```

Try

```
$recordset=mysql_query($query);
while($result = mysql_fetch_array($recordset)){
}
```

Note: MySQL API is long deprecated, better move away from it before you are forced to

Comment: You should not encourage OP to make use of a Deprecated API.

Comment: Noted. I'm on a conversion project now to switch over, but this area is still on the old deprecated API.

Answer (score 0):

You should do like this:

```
$query = mysql_query($query);
while($result = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
```

Answer (score 0):

You could retrieve and decode your parameters with the following code. (Based on @Matteo Tassinari answer)

```
$table = $_GET['table'];
//This could be a SQL injection
$query = "SELECT * FROM " . mysql_real_escape_string($table);

$jsonOut = array();
$result = mysql_query($query);

while($result = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{
    $newArray = array();

    foreach ($result as $k => $v) {
        $newArray[$k] = urldecode($v);
    }
    $jsonOut[] = $newArray;
}

echo (json_encode($jsonOut));
```